# Лагают некоторые программы windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Steam, opera gx, vs code лагают после переустановки windows 10. форматнул диск и накатил с флешки. винда одна и таже.
Компьютер не загружен.
Иногда программы перестают лагать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Что-то мне подказывает, что у вас проблемы с жестким диском